# Should dates be an embedded document?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I am using Mongoid 3. I have a Video model. Should `dates` be an embedded document or an `Array` type?

If I have this structure:

```
{
      :id => 2,
      :dates => [
        {
          :date => Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d').to_i,
          :views => {
            :non_uniques => 1,
            :uniques => 1,
            :countries => {
              :us => 1,
              :uk => 1
            }
          },
          :likes => 1,
          :comments => 1,
        }
      ]
}
```

Moreover, should `views`, `countries` be an embedded document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are planning to capture the additional information with the date , i think your current schema is correct . One aspect is also need to be consider , how you are going to use the data or query. If you want to see the total views and likes for a video for particular date i think your approach is correct , but if you are going to show overall likes and view rather than daily then array will be better. It is typically what you are doing is correct from the sense of NoSQL and embedded document but in last it all depends what all you want to query . Here your reading of daily statistic will be very fast.

Comment: So `dates`, `views` and `countries` will be separate models? i.e. `video ebeds_many dates`, `dates embeds_many views`, `views embeds_many countries`? Sounds right?

Comment: Yup , it will be OK , as I have stated if your query most of the time to show the video with all these information. Even you can have one more collection like country in case you want more detail to keep about the country for some other view but in case of video statistic  as you just want to show country name , keep only the name of the country in the Video document.